# Load Dash Manifest with DRM content with ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, android-drm

I have a dash manifest which needs to be loaded in ExoPlayer, which is also DRM protected.

I can't seem to find any example as to how to achieve that other than using `JWPlayer Android`
which did not work. `executeProvisionRequest` or `executeKeyRequest` was never called on loading my content.

Is there a simpler way to do this with ExoPlayer?

```
PlaylistItem content = new PlaylistItem.Builder()
            .file("MY_MANIFEST_FILE_PATH")
            .mediaDrmCallback(new WidevineMediaDrmCallback())
            .build();

    mPlayerView.load(content);




public class WidevineMediaDrmCallback implements MediaDrmCallback {
  @Override
  public byte[] executeProvisionRequest(UUID uuid, ExoMediaDrm.ProvisionRequest provisionRequest) throws Exception {
    String url = request.getDefaultUrl() + "&signedRequest=" + new String(request.getData());
    return Util.executePost(url, null, null); 
  }

  @Override
  public byte[] executeKeyRequest(UUID uuid, ExoMediaDrm.KeyRequest request) throws Exception {
    String url = request.getLicenseServerUrl();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
        url = defaultUri;
    }
    return Util.executePost(url, request.getData(), null);
  }
}
```